# iphone zombie not detected by instruments

Tags: iphone, instruments, zombie-process

Using the simulator with xcode 4, when I push a new view onto my navigation controller I get an exc_bad_access error. With NSZombies enabled, I run the profiler, but no zombies are detected.  I've placed a million break points trying to identify where the memory allocation problem is, but to no avail.  Does anyone have any suggestions for hunting down a zombie that instruments does not detect?

Comment: You mean your getting an exc_bad_access error when you call the navigationController's pushViewController method? Does any of the code on the view to be pushed run before your app crashes?

Comment: just figured it out.  somehow the return statement for the picker title for row delegate was missing and this caused the error.  i was going crazy looking for a deallocated instance, but this was a different problem entirely.

Comment: Well, glad you got that sorted :)